# How to pass the multiple data with different datatypes from ViewModel to Activity/Fragment using LiveData

Tags: android, mvvm, android-fragmentactivity, android-livedata

Scenario is having a Shared ViewModel (`SharedViewModel`) for my activity(parent) and fragments(children) communication.

The flow is as below:

1. Button click on FragmentA triggers the method

```
    viewmodel.replace(fragment: Fragment, tag: String)
```

2. In viewmodel,

```
    replaceFragment(fragment: Fragment, tag: String? = null) {
         ????
    }
```

3. Activity receives the data from viewmodel in

```
    viewmodel.replaceFragment.observe{
        //this will recieve the data from step 2
        // Here FragmentA will be replaced by FragmentB
        //Here I need the two data (fragment, tag), but receives the fragment or tag
    }
```

Please note the ??? in step 2, I want to send the `fragment: Fragment` and `tag: String` data from `viewmodel` to `Activity` via LiveData, but its only able to send one variable at a time.

I need to pass the two variables of different types from viewmodel to activity using `LiveData`.

I hope there might be some solution to this issue

Please help me regarding the issue.